# Report Server Reports Hanging

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, ssrs-2014

I'm working on a issue with heavily fragmented indexes on a large production DB. I've pretty much identified the indexes that are heavily fragmented, including those that are not really being used. I plan to rebuild some and remove others. So my next step is to devise a before and after time test.

One of the symptoms of this is SSRS reports taking about an hour to render. I'm new to Reports Services. I can see that a report is being embedded in the ASPX page using a ReportViewer control with the ServerPort ReportPath and ReportServerUrl properties set. My problem is trying to figure out how to time the display of the report from start to finish in the code-behind. I can write the start time to a file in the Page_Load but I can't figure out how to record the end time... Pre-Render could just hang and I'm not sure if this is the only page lifecycle event I can tap into to record this. Should I use a Windows Service, and if so, how would I trigger/record the start and end times that way?

I'd really appreciate some feedback on if this is possible via the display page's code-behind.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the Reporting Services execution logs. That contains several timed events such as data retrieval time, render time, process time and the actual start and end time. Check `ReportServer.dbo.Executionlog` and `ReportServer.dbo.Catalog`

Comment: I can only see an ExecutionLogStorage table which has these fields. I tried running this: "SELECT TOP (10) * FROM ExecutionLogStorage ORDER BY TimeDataRetrieval DESC" but got Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.

Comment: They should be there (Views). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/report-server-executionlog-and-the-executionlog3-view
  Also makes ure the retention period in the reports server config is not set to 0.

Comment: Not sure where to check that? Running just SSMS on my local (32GB) and no matter how I filter my queries I keep getting an out of memory exception. Looking at my memory usage and it's nowhere near peaking when my queries are run. How can I determine which report the ReportID filed is referring to?

Comment: Thanks for your help Alan. I got around the memory issue by running the query with the SQLCMD tool. Please feel free to add this as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/sqlcmd-run-transact-sql-script-files

Comment: I've added an answer with more details about the execution logs. I'm not sure why they are not visible. This assumes SSRS running in native (not sharepoint) mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking in the Reporting Services execution logs. That contains several timed events such as data retrieval time, render time, process time and the actual start and end time. Check ReportServer.dbo.Executionlog and ReportServer.dbo.Catalog

To check the log settings. Connect to your SSRS server using SQL Server Management Studio (not the database engine, select Reporting Services from the connection dialogue). Once connected, right-click the server and choose properties. On the logging tab you will see the number of days history to retain. By default this is 60 days.

Assuming that is no zero then you can do a simple query like this to get the report execution details.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM ReportServer..ExecutionLog e
       JOIN ReportServer..Catalog c
          ON e.ReportID = c.ItemID
    WHERE c.name = 'myReportName'
```